# AngularJS directives - set scrollbar at right position

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have, as posted in other threads, this directive. 
What I will achieve is, that the user scrolls up and afterwars data is reloaded from backend (simulated in directive at bottom).
My problem now is after reloading the data and adding into eisting array, what to do with scroll bar - how can I make it to set the scroll bar to the position where it should be (where new loaded data starts)
Is there a possibility or concept to do this.

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myProject.common')
    .directive('asScrollTop', asScrollTop);

function asScrollTop() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { chatMessagesOfUser: '=' },
        link: link
    };
    return directive;

    ////////////

    function link(scope, element, attr) {
        console.log(element);
        element.on('scroll', function() {
          if(element[0].scrollTop <= 0) {

              for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                  var newChatMessage = {};
                  newChatMessage.color = '#00ff00';
                  newChatMessage.confirmation = false;
                  newChatMessage.id = '57b05e24ce861d23bec293df';
                  newChatMessage.links = null;
                  newChatMessage.messageBody = 'das ist die neue message';
                  newChatMessage.messageUserConnectionId = '57b05e24ce861d23bec293e0';
                  newChatMessage.name = 'Mag. Testname testname';
                  newChatMessage.read = true;
                  newChatMessage.time = '13.08.2016 11:23';
                  newChatMessage.userCreatedMessageId = '"5589929b887dc1fdb501cdba"';

                  scope.chatMessagesOfUser.splice(0, 0, newChatMessage);
              }
              scope.$apply();
          }
        });
      }
}
```

})();

Comment: If you can locate the position at which the new data has loaded, you could use the `window.scrollTo` function. This function allows you to programmatically scroll to a specified X and Y position.

Answer (score 0):

`window.scrollTo` is the javascript function used to scroll the page to a certain position. [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo):

> Scrolls to a particular set of coordinates in the document.

and

> #### Example
>
> ```
> window.scrollTo( 0, 1000 );
> ```

You can use this function to scroll your page, but only if you know the Y position of the new data.

Perhaps you should consider inserting anchor tags in your data to use as reference points for `scrollTo`.